# Excel VBA- how to identify cells with scientific notation

Tags: excel, vba, notation

I have searched SO, and am unsuccessful in trying to find the solution--  how do you identify cells in a column that are in scientific notation via Excel vba?

Here is the code where I am trying to isolate via autofilter rows with scientific notation...

```
Private Sub cmdMoveScientificNotation_Click()

Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim objWB As Excel.Workbook
Dim objWBtoAdd As Excel.Workbook
Dim newWS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim objWS As Excel.Worksheet
Dim i As Long
Dim Lrow As Long
Dim strSearch As String
Dim myRange As Range
Dim Cell As Range


Set objExcel = New Excel.Application

objExcel.Visible = True

Set objWB = Workbooks.Open("C:\TEST\Drop\Bank.xlsx", , False)
Set objWBtoAdd = Workbooks.Add
Set newWS = objWBtoAdd.ActiveSheet

Set objWS = objWB.ActiveSheet

    With objWS

        Lrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        myRange = .Range("A1:V" & Lrow)

            For Each Cell In myRange
                If (Cell.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00") Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=strSearch
                .SpecialCells(xlTypeVisible).EntireRow.Copy
                End If

            Next Cell


    End With

newWS.PasteSpecial


End Sub
```

Comment: Do you require this to be done specifically in VBA? Or do you just need to visually identify?  If you just want to know "which ones are Scientific Notation, they are the numbers with an "E" in the middle, like `123E+00`

Comment: Sometimes people overthink things and assume they need VBA when they really dont. Sometimes VBA is overkill so why not propose a simple solution that OP may not be aware of - even if OP is not able to use the solution, future people searching for this question may find the answer useful.

Comment: @urdearboy "sometimes" is an understatement!  As mentioned the clue the the knowledge level required for what's being asked, compared to what's required for VBA.  I think the answer the OP is looking for is not even using the Number Format dialog, but rather ***Look for the E!*** :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This will work for ONE cell and return a msgbox if the range has been formatted to scientific notation.

```
Sub BillNye
Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("A1")

If (MyRange.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00") Then
MsgBox "Scientific"
End If
End Sub
```

This will scan range A1:A10 for scientific format and post a comment in the cell in columb B if it is scientific. You will need to modify your ranges and offset the equation as needed. As the code stands, you can filter column B for "Scientific" to only see values in scientific format.

```
Sub BillNye()

Dim MyRange As Range
Set MyRange = Range("A1:A10")
Dim Cell As Range

For Each Cell In MyRange
    If (Cell.NumberFormat = "0.00E+00") Then
    Cell.Offset(, 1) = "Scientific"
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

I would suggest modifying the range to your last row to be dynamic (unless you only need to use this once, then static range is fine.)

Comment: Could just as easily be `0.000E+00`

Comment: Tim, what I’m attempting to do is autofilter for cells in scientific notation so that I can move those out to another worksheet and then add an apostrophe to the beginning.  I have attempted to do this (add apostrophe) to the entire column but with rows exceeding 200k, it goes really slow.  So I figured to maybe just focus on filtering out the rows in scientific notation instead

Comment: Thanks urdearboy— this seems to be what I’m looking for. MANY thanks-  I really appreciate this.

Comment: Urdearboy- could you please specify how to express the last row as dynamic?  I am having problems with:

Comment: The column is #2

Comment: I edited my initial question to include the code in which I'm attempting to autofilter rows with scientific notation, copy/paste to new worksheet...

Answer (score 7):

Something like:

```
If IsNumeric(cell.Value) And cell.text like "*E*" Then
```

Excel sometimes switches to scientific notation without changing the number format if the number is too long to fit the width of the cell.

If you only need to look for cells which have been formatted as scientific then look at:

```
cell.NumberFormat
```

Comment: This is the correct answer based on the information given +1 (I suspect misinformation may have been given, and now OI'm really curious if I'm correct!)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you may have used the [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) tag on your question error.  If you are just trying to tell at a glance which cells are Scientific Notation, you could...

1. Look for cells that have an "E" in the middle, like `123E+00` (see below).
2. Highlight a cell and check it's format by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> to open the *Number Format* dialo,g where you can see whether `Scientific` is selected.

---

### Example:

In the example below there are a mix of cells formatted as ***`Number`*** as as ***`Scientific`***.  I highlight the cells formatted as **Scientific Notation** so you can see the difference.

[image: img]

---

### More Information:

- Office.com : [**Display numbers in scientific (exponential) notation**](https://support.office.com/article/display-numbers-in-scientific-exponential-notation-f85a96c0-18a1-4249-81c3-e934cd2aae25)
- Microsoftm : [**How to control & understand settings in the Format Cells dialog box**](https://support.microsoft.com/help/264372/how-to-control-and-understand-settings-in-the-format-cells-dialog-box)

[image: img]

---

### Edit:

I'm still not exactly sure what the goal was on this one but here's an alternate solution, if the goal is to identify which cells have values currently *displayed* in Scientific Notation.

For example, in some cases, a cell will automatically format (self-abbreviate) in Scientific Notation when the column is resized to be too narrow to display the entire (standard notation) number.

In VBA, the cell's `.Text` property always returns the *displayed* "formatted" value (as opposed to the `.Value` property which returns the *actual* "raw" underlying value).

Therefore a function like this could be used to identify which cells are currently displayed using Scientific Notation:

```
Function displayedAsScientific(c As Range) As Boolean
  Application.Volatile
  displayedAsScientific = IsNumeric(c.Value) And InStr(c.Text, "E") > 0
End Function
```

<sub>This image may or may not help demonstrate:</sub>

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Since the question says VBA in the title and is tagged *vba*, I'm pretty sure the poster is asking for a programmatic solution.

Comment: Yes, VBA please

Comment: Could you please clarify how to specify the last row as dynamic— I’m having problems with that...